# Bad output using structs and pointers

Tags: c, memory

I'm trying to make "objects" and manage this in C to "free" and "realloc" memory space later, but I have a problem with the output in this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct {
    // Param
    char name[16];
    char code[16];
    
} Employee;

void print(Employee *object)
{
    printf("\n \n - Name: [%s], Code: [%s]\n", object->name, object->code);
}


int main(){

    Employee *aPerson = (Employee *)malloc(sizeof(Employee));
    
    // Setting name:
    char select[1];
    do {    
        printf("\nWrite the employee name: ");
        scanf("%s", aPerson->name);
        printf("\nThe name is <%s>? (y/n): ", aPerson->name);
        scanf("%s", &select[0]);
        select[0] = tolower(select[0]);
    }while(select[0] != 'y');
    
    printf("\n[*]\t%s \n[]\t%s \n[&]\t%s", *aPerson, aPerson, &aPerson->name);
    printf("\n[->]\t%s", aPerson->name);
    print(aPerson);

}
```

I realized that if I type "n" and set the name again, the code works, but if I get the name right in the first try the code doesnt work, my output when I have this problem is:

```
> ↑d)}·⌂
```

*Ty, for your time.*

Comment: Without event looking `scanf("%s", &select[0]);` is undefined behavior. You need at least 2 characters: one for the data and one for a terminating zero - you only have space for one char.

Comment: Tip: An array of one is usually completely useless. This is equivalent to `char` which **cannot** hold a C string of length > 0.

Comment: You might want to use `char` and then `scanf("%c", &select)` for a single character.

Comment: And you should use `if( scanf("%15s", aPerson->name) == 1 ) { ... }`  Always place a width specifier so you don't overflow the array bounds, and always check the return value to ensure that some data was written to the variable.

Comment: scanf using %s adds a null automatically, so if your array is of size 1, your program will write in a invalid memory area, causing unpredictable behavior. I tested it just using selected[2] and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

I have fixed your code, the error was on the line:

```
char select[1];
```

where you delclared a string of length 1 but, since in C strings are null-terminated, there is no space for the '\0' character. Then when you call **scanf** it tries to write the null-termination but, as I said above, there is no space reserved on the stack and that is undefined behavior.

---

Here is the fixed code:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    // Param
    char name[16];
    char code[16];
    
} Employee;

void print(Employee *object)
{
    printf("\n \n - Name: [%s], Code: [%s]\n", object->name, object->code);
}


int main(){

    Employee *aPerson = (Employee *)malloc(sizeof(Employee));
    
    // Setting name:
    char select[2];     // <---- Here is where I've made the correction
    do {    
        printf("\nWrite the employee name: ");
        scanf("%s", aPerson->name);
        printf("\nThe name is <%s>? (y/n): ", aPerson->name);
        scanf("%1s", select);
        select[0] = tolower(select[0]);
    }while(select[0] != 'y');
    
    printf("\n[*]\t%s \n[]\t%s \n[&]\t%s", *aPerson, aPerson, &aPerson->name);
    printf("\n[->]\t%s", aPerson->name);
    print(aPerson);

    free(aPerson);      // <------ I've added a free for the malloc.
}
```

Comment: What is the question being asked?

Comment: ricxk asked the reason why his code was not printing properly the strings that are in the struct `Employee`, his output were random charactes.